# Construtor with long parameter list OR multiple setters?

Tags: java, constructor, long-parameter-list

To initialize an instance, we can use either a default constuctor and a number of setters, or a constructor with a long parameter list. In the latter way the object state may remain unchanged after the object is generated(because there is not setter), but a long parameter list is ugly and error-prone. In the former way the long parameter list is avoid, but the object state may be changed by setters by mistake after the object has been completely created.

I need such an object that its internal fields should remain unchanged after the object is created, while I do not like long parameter list. What is the best practice to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern):

```
Foo foo = new FooBuilder().setBar(...).setBaz(...).build();
```

Comment: +1: Builders can also have constructor arguments for some of the mandatory fields. i.e. you don't lose anything by using the pattern.

Comment: +1 _Item 2: Consider a Builder when Faced with Many Constructor Parameters_

Comment: When you are considering a builder pattern, also consider whether the parameters really are individual values or are perhaps part of groups of attributes, that could be promoted to classes. So you can replace this constructor signature, with another one with fewer parameters but each parameter represents a higher level of abstraction. This might not be the case, in which case a Builder pattern is great, but you should at least consider it.

Answer (score 2):

A long parameter list could (but doesn't have to) mean that the class should be refactored to smaller classes.